# Como criar um gráfico com os dados da última linha automaticamente ao fechar o formulário?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Estou fazendo um formulário em VBA com informações sobre alguns municípios (que estão na ComboBox) e suas respectivas metas a serem batidas (que está como uma fórmula direto na planilha).

No formulário eu insiro as informações que eu quero (alguns dados dos municípios) e uma coluna específica na planilha contem a fórmula que faz a porcentagem da meta concluída até o momento.

Gostaria de fazer com que, ao fechar o formulário, automaticamente me gerasse um gráfico com a porcentagem da meta e o nome do município, porém esta informação da meta não está no código e sim direto na planilha.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim range1 As Range
Dim objeto As Control

Sheets("REGISTRO").Select
If Range("A2").Value = "" Then
    Set range1 = Range("A2")
Else
    Set range1 = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
End If

range1.Value = UserForm2.ComboBox1.Value
range1.Offset(0, 1).Value = UserForm2.TextBox1.Value
range1.Offset(0, 2).Value = UserForm2.TextBox2.Value
range1.Offset(0, 4).Value = UserForm2.TextBox3.Value
range1.Offset(0, 5).Value = UserForm2.TextBox4.Value
range1.Offset(0, 6).Value = UserForm2.TextBox5.Value
range1.Offset(0, 7).Value = UserForm2.TextBox6.Value

'criando gráfico
range1.Select
range1.Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("REGISTRO!A2,REGISTRO!H2")

'fechando a aplicação
UserForm2.Hide

For Each objeto In UserForm2.Controls
    On Error Resume Next
    objeto.Value = ""
Next
```

A coluna da porcentagem da meta é a J.
Tentei gravar uma macro pra fazer isso, mas queria fazer com que o gráfico fosse gerado a partir da última linha, ou seja, o último município registrado no formulário ja me retornasse o gráfico com a porcentagem concluída até aquele momento.

Acredito que o problema esteja nessa linha "Source", mas não to entendendo como fazer da forma que eu quero.

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0):

O ideal seria você criar outro range depois de fazer o set do range1 e usar o novo range (range_grafico).
Considerando que a última coluna (de dados) será a coluna 1 + 9 ou "J", já que o range1 já vai estar na coluna 1. Esse rage_grafico você usaria como 'Source' do 'Activechart'

```
Dim range gráfico as Range
'(...)
Set range_grafico = Range(range1, range1.Offset(, 9))
```

Mas, como algo rápido, veja se isto pode ajudar. Troque este código:

```
'criando gráfico
range1.Select
range1.Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("REGISTRO!A2,REGISTRO!H2")
```

Por este código:

```
'criando gráfico
Range(range1, range1.Offset(0, 9)).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
```